# Next.js 14 - Cannot import 'next/font/local' (module-not-found) but 'next/font/google' works

Tags: next.js, fonts, next.js14

I am using Next.js 14.1.0 with the `app/` directory and I am trying to import and use custom local fonts but I cannot import `next/font/local` despite the fact that I can import `next/font/google` normally with no errors.

I have a `custom_font.ttf` file in a `public/fonts` directory, and I am doing the following in order to import it inside my `layout.tsx` file:

```
import localFont from "next/font/local";

const custom = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: '../../public/fonts/custom_font.ttf',
      weight: '400'
    }
  ],
  variable: '--font-custom'
})
...
```

But I get the following vague error on both the webpage and the terminal with no error log anywhere as to how to fix it or what is causing it:

```
./app/layout.tsx
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

If I just have `import "next/font/local"` the program moves past it and it doesn't complain but as soon as I import localFont from it, the error appears.

However for some reason I can still import and use any Google fonts normally with no issue even though they originate from the same parent `next/font/` directory with:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
...
```

I've tried deleting the `node_modules/` and `.next/` directories and `package-lock.json` files and regenerated them but it didn't work.

What is the best way to go about solving this?